# How to combine standard deviations for paired samples?

Tags: standard-deviation, paired-data, pooling

I have a group of individuals X, each member of the group has had two measures taken: *i* and *j*.

I have the means and SDs of *i* and *j*. I also know the correlation coefficient between *i* and *j*: *r*.

I am able to calculate the combined mean of *i* and *j*: *k*

How do I calculate the standard deviation of *k*? The formula I have for combining SD, is for separate populations and therefore overestimates the SD:[image]

Many thanks for your help,

Rob

Comment: Are you asking for the standard *error* of the grand mean?

Comment: I am asking for the standard deviation of the grand mean (although I imagine I would be able to calculate this from the standard error). Please let me know if that doesn't make sense?

Comment: What kind of a thing is the standard deviation of a mean other than the standard error?

Comment: Isn't the standard deviation equivalent to the standard error multiplied by the square root of the sample size?

Comment: I have the means and standard deviations of i and j, and the correlation between i and j, and wish to calculate the SD of K.

Comment: To clarify: by *k* do you mean a new sample that, for each group member, contains the mean of that person's measurements of *i* and *j*? Or do you mean a single number corresponding to the grand mean of samples *i* and *j* combined?

Comment: Does this Q&A http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26523/what-is-the-pooled-standard-deviation-of-paired-samples?rq=1 help?

Comment: Dear Ruben - thank you for clarifying, k is effectively a new sample that for each group member contains the mean of that persons measurement of i and j. I am able to calculate the grand mean (which is also the mean of k) but I am unsure as to how to calculate the standard deviation of k.

Comment: Dear mdewey, unfortunately I do not think that answers the question

Answer (score 1):

Based on your clarification that $k$ is a new sample, below is a formula for the SD of $k$ in terms of the SDs and correlation of $i$ and $j$:
$$
\sigma_k = \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}\sigma_i^2+\frac{1}{4}\sigma_j^2+\frac{1}{2}\rho\sigma_i\sigma_j}
$$
Where $\sigma_i$, $\sigma_j$ and $\sigma_k$ are the standard deviations of samples $i$, $j$ and $k$ (respectively) and $\rho$ is the correlation between $i$ and $j$.

See also [this wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_of_uncertainty#Example_formulas) (I'm simply applying the second example formula here, with $a=b=\frac{1}{2}$).